# Qt starting QTcpServer from main...strange behaviour

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qtnetwork

Given the two sets of code below, I am really confused as to why the first one works as expected and the second one doesn't. When I launch my application with code A I can successfully connect to the server from external clients, in my case telnet. However when I run it with code B the client can't connect, on telnet I receive a could not connect error. Does the `server` instance get killed after initiation ? the event loop is started on both sets of code though, so why would it work on one and not the other ?

**CODE A**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  QString port(argv[1]);
  bool convert;
  int portNum = port.toInt(&convert);
  MyServer server;
  server.startServer(portNum);

  return a.exec();
}
```

**CODE B**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  if(argc == 2){
    QString port(argv[1]);
    bool convert;
    int portNum = port.toInt(&convert);
    MyServer server;
    server.startServer(portNum);
  }
  return a.exec();
}
```

Thanks for any help , greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the command line  you used to run the app? e.g. `a.out 1234`?

Comment: @AnthonyKong I added the argument in the run step of qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of your `MyServer server` is the braces of the if `(argc == 2)` condition. So as soon as execution comes out of if condition brace, `server` gets destroyed.

Create `server` outside your if condition and it will work.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot :) . It had to be something trivial didn't it.